# How to obtain histogram of a BufferedImage

Tags: java, jframe, histogram, bufferedimage

I am creating a JFrame and importing an image into that frame using a BufferedImage. I am looking to obtain the histogram of the image that is being imported. How can this be done? Here is the code for my image:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String path = "src/logo.jpg";
        File file = new File(path);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(label);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocation(0,200);
        f.setVisible(true);}}
```

Now once the image appears I would like an output to reflect the histogram values.

Comment: the below post will be helpful 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090435/how-to-plot-histogram-using-rgb-pixel-value

also please read the official documentation 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/Histogram.html